# Is it possible to open URL in C++ WITHOUT using <windows.h>?

Tags: c++

I found it a little tricky that some compiler can't run the `<windows.h>` header file. Is it possible to open an URL in C++ without using `<windows.h>` ?

Here's my code, but using `<windows.h>`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,"https://ssur.cc/Easy-Way-To-Open-URL-In-CPP",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would also mention that it is impossible to open a URL using `windows.h` on Linux...

Comment: Why does this code not work for you?

Comment: Well the code is working smooth...But I'm just curious about the possibility of not using `<windows.h>`

Comment: If you have a problem with using windows.h you might want to ask about that problem first, providing a detailed description of what you have tried and what results you have got.

Answer (score 1):

You could just forward declare the function in question and let the linker handle it.

But if your compiler has issues with windows.h it will probably not support all Windows platforms/architectures. But assuming the calling-convention used by the compiler just happens to match you can do something like this:

```
typedef void* M_HINSTANCE;
typedef void* M_HWND; 
#define M_SW_SHOW 5

// should be __stdcall , but if your compiler has trouble with windows.h, then it will probably also have trouble with __stdcall
extern "C" M_HINSTANCE ShellExecuteA(M_HWND   hwnd,
const char* lpOperation,
const char* lpFile,
const char* lpParameters,const char* lpDirectory,
int nShowCmd
);

int main(){
    ShellExecuteA(0,0,"https://ssur.cc/Easy-Way-To-Open-URL-In-CPP",0,0,M_SW_SHOW );
    return 0;
}
```

You will still need to link to `Shell32.lib` and like I mentioned you might get linker errors on some platforms for mismatching calling conventions.

Alternatively you can try to start the shell as a generic process like

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    std::system("cmd.exe /c start https://ssur.cc/Easy-Way-To-Open-URL-In-CPP");
    // or something like:
    // std::system("explorer.exe https://ssur.cc/Easy-Way-To-Open-URL-In-CPP");
    // or on some other non-windows platforms:
    // std::system("open https://ssur.cc/Easy-Way-To-Open-URL-In-CPP");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh, it seems that some online compilers don't support `<windows.h>` .

So I changed the compiler to Dev C++ , and it's running quite well.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Why would you open an URL on an online compiler?